# jQuery toggle -> get/post

Tags: jquery, http, get, toggle

I'm having trouble with Flip Switch Toggles in jQuery. I need the buttons to toggle between HTTP_GET requests when pressed.

**The HTML output (there's some PHP behind this)**

```
<label for="device-2">Power outlet</label>
<select name="device-2" id="device-2" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

**I'm able to get the device powered on/off but I have to be able to make two separate HTTP_GETs (turnon and turnoff)**

```
$("#device-2").on("change", function() {
    $.get( "functions/caller.php", { action: "turnon", device: "2" });
});
```

**I've tried out this toggle function but it's just dead. It doesn't seem to make any HTTP requests when I've troubleshooted it in browser console**

```
$("#device-2").toggle(function() {
    $.get( "functions/caller.php", { action: "turnon", device: "2" });
}, function() {
    $.get( "functions/caller.php", { action: "turnoff", device: "2" });
});
```

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$("#device-2").on("change", function() {
    var state = $(this).val();
    $.get( "functions/caller.php", { action: state, device: "2" });
});
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Just edited this into my server-side code and now I can remotely control my whole house!!!

1.000.000 thanks for simplifying the code also!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#device-2").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.get( "functions/caller.php", { action: "turn" + value, device: "2" });
});
```

Assuming that your caller.php file accepts the actions "turnon" and "turnoff", this should dynamically change the `$.get` call based on the selected element's `value`.